# How can tables be excluded from mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM database";
```

I would like to exclude table "users", "cars" and "gifts" for example. How can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query table names directly from the `information_schema` database. Assuming your database name is in the variable `$your_database_name`:

```
mysql_select_db("information_schema");
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA = '$your_database_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('users','cars','gifts')";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database_name WHERE tables_in_database_name NOT IN ('users');
```

And if you neither want cars and users

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database_name WHERE tables_in_database_name NOT IN ('users', 'cars');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to display tables, then while `echo` you may do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   if($row[0] == 'users' || $row[0] == 'cars' || $row[0] == 'gifts')
      continue;
   else
      echo $row[0];
}
```